# PLSQL/ How to add values during iteration of associative array

Tags: sql, plsql, varray

i need something like this in procedure PLSQL

```
 arrayCount:=parArray.Count;
 For i In 1 .. arrayCount Loop
    lsPar(i):=parArray(i);
 End Loop;
```

is it possible? Thx for advice! :)

Comment: :I think you have not tried it once ,try this and you will know whether this is possible or not

Comment: I tried it and it can't be done... it is asking me for DECLARE lsPar

Comment: @user1518308: If you'll post the full procedure, we can help you figure out the problem. That error message makes it sound like you never declared `lsPar`.

Comment: But I dont need to add values into lsPar... I need to add value into lsPar1, lsPar2, lsPar3, lsPar4 and these variables I declared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're working on `oracle` ,then this piece of anonymous block will work for you

```
 declare
    TYPE parArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64) index by binary_integer;
    v_parArray parArray;
    arrayCount number;
    lsPar parArray;

    begin
    v_parArray(1):='A';
    v_parArray(2):='B';
    v_parArray(3):='C';

    arrayCount:=v_parArray.Count;
       For i In 1 .. arrayCount 
       Loop
          lsPar(i):=v_parArray(i);
       End Loop;

     arrayCount:=lsPar.Count;
        For i In 1 .. arrayCount
         Loop
          dbms_output.put_line('The value of Ispar at index '||i||' is '||lsPar(i));
        End Loop;
     end;
```

**Output**

```
 The value of Ispar at index 1 is A
 The value of Ispar at index 2 is B
 The value of Ispar at index 3 is C
```